# set value for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to docker-compose up cli command only

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

If I want to provide custom value for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `docker-compose up` cli command how would I do that?

Is it possible to provide this through cli or I need to use docker-compose.yml file (this solution I would like to skip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `docker-compose run`, `docker-compose up` does not provide this - unfortunately. Alternatively, you can make use of `env_file` for this:

```
services:
  webapi:
    image: aspnetcore-image
    env_file:
        - .env
```

By creating a file named `.env` (it can be named as desired) and placing it in the appropriate directory (here it is placed in the same directory as docker-compose.yml), `docker-compose up` will then export the respective env vars to the docker container.